# detect all urls in img tag in a large string + android

Tags: java, android

I have a string content in android like :

```
xyz xyx xyz<br /><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="https://blablab.png" alt="Loading..." /></p>abc</p><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="https://blablab2.png" alt="Loading..." /><div>abc</div><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="https://blablab3.png" alt="Loading..." />
```

Here, I have to retrieve value of src attributes(url of image file) of all the img tags and replace the img tags with its base 64 value. How can i do that, ie. first detect values of all the src attributes and then replace the img tags with their base 64 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are Chuck Norris or Jon Skeet, you shouldn't use RegEx to match HTML. I would suggest using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). Here is an example using the string from your question:

```
String html = "xyz xyx xyz<br /><img style=\"max-width: 100%;\" src=\"https://blablab.png\" alt=\"Loading...\" /></p>abc</p><img style=\"max-width: 100%;\" src=\"https://blablab2.png\" alt=\"Loading...\" /><div>abc</div><img style=\"max-width: 100%;\" src=\"https://blablab3.png\" alt=\"Loading...\" />";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements imgs = document.select("img[src]");
for (Element img : imgs) {
  img.attr("src", "http://placehold.it/350x150");
}
String newHtml = document.html();
```

Comment: how can i replace the img tag with its base 64 value?

Comment: Google "replace tag jsoup site:stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Matcher`. The following page gives some examples: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html. The idea is to write a regular expression that matches an `img`-tag with a `src`-attribute, find each match, get the non-constant parts from regex-groups and then do the replacement.